# Sequentially reorganize a vector in R

Tags: r, sorting, vector

I have a numeric element `z` as below:

```
> sort(z)
  [1]  1  5  5  5  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  9  9
```

I would like to sequentially reorganize this element so to have

```
> z
  [1]  1  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  5  5
```

I guess converting z to a factor and use it as an index should be the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You answered it yourself really:

```
as.integer(factor(sort(z)))
```

---

I know this has been accepted already but I decided to look inside `factor()` to see how it's done there. It more or less comes down to this:

```
x <- sort(z)
match(x, unique(x))
```

Which is an extra line I suppose but it should be faster if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
z = sort(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
cumsum(diff(z)) + 1
 [1]  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
[26]  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6  6
[51]  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
[76]  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10
```

Note that `diff` omits the first element of the series. So to compensate:

```
c(1, cumsum(diff(z)) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using `rle`:

```
z = sort(sample(1:10, 100, replace = TRUE))
rle_result = rle(sort(z))
rep(rle_result$values, rle_result$lengths)

> rep(rle_result$values, rle_result$lengths)
  [1]  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  3  3  3  3
 [26]  3  3  3  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  5  6  6  6
 [51]  6  6  6  6  6  6  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  7  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
 [76]  8  8  8  8  8  8  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9 10 10 10 10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rep(seq_along(rle(x)$l), rle(x)$l)
```